# Why value of $id my projecct in codeigniter is NULL

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried to find why my $id is still NULL, but in the other project it works
please help me to find the error

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Error

> Message: Call to a member function get_pengajuan() on null

Filename: .\magang\application\controllers\Surat.php

Line Number: 40

Backtrace:

File: .\magang\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Line 40 is `$data['pengajuan'] = $this->MPengajuan->get_pengajuan($id);`

**Controller:**

```
    public function edit($id)
{
    $this->load->view("header");
    $this->load->view("home/user");
    $this->load->view("home/admin");
    $this->load->view("topbar");
    $this->load->view("admin/edit_surat");
    $this->load->view("footer");
    $data['pengajuan'] = $this->MPengajuan->get_pengajuan($id);
}
```

**Model:**

```
public function get_pengajuan($id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT pengajuan.* , instansi_magang.nama_instansi FROM pengajuan,instansi_magang WHERE pengajuan.id_instansi=instansi_magang.id_instansi AND id_pengajuan='$id'");
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

**View:**

```
<?php
      foreach ($pengajuan as $pengajuan_item){
              echo form_open_multipart('Surat/edit/'.$pengajuan_item['id_pengajuan']); 
      }
?>
```

Comment: If you are going to supply errors with line numbers, you should add the relevant line numbers to your code.

Comment: The problem might not be with the id, but rather `$this->MPengajuan`.

Comment: still same NULL :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution 
that i forgot to load Model in construct with

```
$this->load->model('MPengajuan');
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest your error is :

1. You don't have to use `form_open_multipart` . Because there is no file to upload.
2. Your controller must use lowercase in your view `('surat/edit/'.$pengajuan_item['id_pengajuan'])`